# How can I send information about user who is trying to book tickets of Eventbrite?

Tags: api, android-widget, embed, checkout, eventbrite

I am trying to implement checkout flow with Eventbrite in my mobile app.
I already know the user's first name, last name, and email.
Is it possible to send this information to Eventbrite during checkout, so users do not have to enter them again while purchasing tickets?

We are building an app that will run on Android and iOS.
Using ReactNative / Heroku / PosgreSQL database

Thanks,
Hema.

Comment: Can you please what have you tried so far or improve the tags as I can see tags related to android widgets as well, thanks.

Comment: Updated description as requested.